# error: `MEMBER` in `class CLASS` does not name a type; C++

Tags: c++, gcc, sfml

Hey there i have constructed a class to store some Information as static Members of the class.
At Compile-time i got the error:

> error: ‘cubeLength’ in ‘class Config’ does not name a type
>
> error: ‘cellColor’ in ‘class Config’ does not name a type

Content of Config.h

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Config {
public: 
    static float     cubeLength ;
    static sf::Color cellColor;
private:
    Config();
    Config(const Config& orig);
};

Config::cubeLength = 10.f; //error thrown here
Config::cellColor  = sf::Color::Magenta;  //error thrown here


#endif  /* CONFIG_H */
```

I am using GNU Compiler on Linux.
Please help me Out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states you need to have the type information in the deceleration.  You need to have:

```
float Config::cubeLength = 10.f;
sf::Color Config::cellColor = sf::Color::Magenta;
```

Comment: that's it, you're my hero :)

Answer (score 1):

The type information of those variables is missing when you do the assignment.

This should fix it:

```
static float Config::cubeLength = 10.f;
static sf::Color Config::cellColor = sf::Color::Magenta;
```